# Одиночный показ всплывающего сообщения Toast

Tags: android, android-toast

В приложении при нажатии на кнопку выводится всплывающее сообщение

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    "Число уже дробное", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

Как запретить показ этого сообщения при уже открытом аналогичном сообщении (если оно погасло, вновь показ разрешён)? Иначе, при последовательном быстром десятикратном нажатии, оно будет выводится 10 раз одно за другим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте один объект `Toast`

```
public static void showToast(String message) {
    if (myToast == null) {
        myToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
    if (!myToast.getView().isShown()) { //случай когда Toast показан не работает
        myToast.setText(message);
        myToast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает